# Como puedo corregir las dependencias

Tags: linux

Estoy tratando de hacer la siguinete instalación sudo apt -f install ngrok-client, pero me genera error con algunas dependencías, cuales son los comandos correctos para que me instale y actualice las dependencias que necesita. En la imagen está el mensaje de error que no me permite hacer la instalación. Estoy usando Ubuntu 16.04 Xenia a 64 bits.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando el comando `apt-get`, tal como lo recomienda el error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install ngrok-client
```

Comment: Ya lo hice, genera los mismos mensajes con los problemas con las dependencias.

Comment: @GarcíaHenry ¿Has intentando bajarlo e instalarlo manualmente?

Comment: Si, ya lo intente, siempre genera errores de dependencias, necesito generar una url que bindee la de http://localhost:3000 ya que estoy tratando de autenticarme con facebook utilizando auth ya que según la respespuesta que me dieron Facebook no puede identificar mi url local y mediante ngrok la puedo enmascarar.

Comment: la parecer es el sqllite el del problema, como podría eliminarlo; dpkg: error processing package sqlitebrowser:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqlitebrowser:i386

Answer (score 1):

Primero Actualiza y Upgrade

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Después prueba la reinstalacion:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ngrok-client
```

Si tienes aun errores de dependencias

```
$sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Seguí los pasos y generó los siguientes errores:                                              Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: sqlitebrowser:i386 (<= 3.5.1-3) but 2.0.0~beta1+ds.1-2 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: sqlitebrowser:i386 (<= 3.5.1-3) but 2.0.0~beta1+ds.1-2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue eliminar las dependencia de sqlite3 y el sqlite3, correr los comandos:

$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade

Se actualizaron los paquetes pendientes y quedó funcionando correctamente.